# Dagger2 Optimal way to inject dependencies from two different classes

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

After searching and trying too many things i'm stuck in some what seems like an easy problem.
Below is my module which is reponsible for injecting retrofit.

```
@Module
public class NetworkingModule
{
    @Provides
    public Retrofit providesRetrofit()
    {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE).create();
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                                        .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
                                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                                        .build();

        return retrofit;
    }


}
```

My NetworkComponent

```
@Component( modules = NetworkingModule.class)
public interface NetworkingComponent {
    void inject(DashboardPresenterImpl target);

    void inject(PicksPresenterImpl picksPresenter);

    void inject(LoadsPresenterImpl loadsPresenter);

    void inject(ShippingPresenterImpl shippingPresenter);

    void inject(GeneralFilePresenterImpl generalFilePresenter);
}
```

A utility class with constructor injection. Please note this class also has injection of AppPreferences.

```
public class AppUtils {
    private Context context;

    @Inject
    AppPreferences preferences;

    @Inject
    public AppUtils(@ActivityContext Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;

        /*ActivityComponent component = DaggerActivityComponent.builder()
                .activityModule(new ActivityModule((Activity) context))
                .build();
        component.inject(this);*/
    }
}
```

Now in my Code i want to achieve this

```
Class MyPresenterImpl{
@Inject
    Retrofit retrofit;

    @Inject
    AppUtils appUtils;
}
```

Please suggest an optimize and good way to achieve the above.

**EDIT**

Added AppPreference.java

```
public class AppPreferences {
    @Inject
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    @Inject
    public AppPreferences(@ActivityContext Context context)
    {
        ApplicationComponent component = DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
                .applicationModule(new ApplicationModule((Application) context.getApplicationContext()))
                .build();
        component.inject(this);

        editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    }

    public void putString(String key, String value)
    {
        editor.putString(key, value).commit();
    }

    public String getString(String key)
    {
        return sharedPreferences.getString(key, null);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please decide on whether you want to use field injection or constructor injection, and hopefully choose **constructor injection**.

```
public class AppUtils {
  private Context context;

  @Inject // field injection?
  AppPreferences preferences;

  @Inject // constructor injection?
  public AppUtils(@ActivityContext Context context)
  {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Dagger won't inject your fields if you use constructor injection and you should not call it yourself afterwards either. Your component should really not contain all those methods to inject your presenter etc.

If you need something, put it in the constructor.

```
public class AppUtils {
  private Context context;
  private AppPreferences preferences;

  @Inject // constructor injection!
  public AppUtils(@ActivityContext Context context, AppPreferences preferences)
  {
    // ...
  }
}
```

The same applies for `MyPresenterImpl`. If you depend on something, put it in the constructor, mark the constructor with `@Inject`, and Dagger will create the object for you with all the dependencies provided.

Your components should only contain `.inject(..)` method for Android framework types (Activities, Fragments, ...) and nothing else.

I also wrote an article recently with [some general concepts](https://blog.davidmedenjak.com/android/2017/11/11/dagger-rules-engagement.html) about the use of Dagger.

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer with easy explanation, but my main question still unanswered i.e `Class MyPresenterImpl{
@Inject
    Retrofit retrofit;

    @Inject
    AppUtils appUtils;
}
Please suggest an optimize and good way to achieve the above.` Now as you can see Retrofit is being proivided by NetworkModule where as i'm using constructor injection in AppUtils. How to inject both without creating a separate component for MyPresenterImpl. Thanks I'll read the blog you shared.

Comment: `Your components should only contain .inject(..) method for Android framework types (Activities, Fragments, ...) and nothing else.` so how to inject in non framework types?

Comment: non framework types should be provided by some module so there will be constructor injection only (no need for calling inject())

Comment: @eCDroid As pointed out, you should just use constructor injection alone. Put every dependency in the constructor, and done.

Comment: Just finished reading your blog, it was helpful and yes dagger can be very confusing in the start, when you feel you are starting to master it, It's just a beginning indeed.

Answer (score 1):

my suggestion:
create context module:

```
@Module
public class ContextModule
{
    Context context;

    public ContextModule(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Provides
    @AppScope
    Context context() {
        return context;
    }
}
```

create SharedPreferences module

```
@Module
public class SharedPreferencesModule
{

    @Provides
    @AppScope
    AppSharedPreferences provideAppSharedPreferences(Context context) {
        return new AppSharedPreferences(context.getSharedPreferences("App",Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
    }
}
```

same way You can create more modules if you need to (for example for AppUtils)

instead of creating separate component for network, create one for your app

```
@Component( modules = {ContextModule.class, NetworkingModule.class, SharedPreferencesModule})
public interface AppComponent {...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer i really appreciate but in this way any class that want to build AppComponent has to provide an instance for ContextModule, NetworkingModule and SharedPreferences while building DaggerAppComponent. Which i think is not an optimal way.

Comment: @eCDroid my recommendation and common practice is to have one AppComponent instance stored and exposed in Application class. Since You can always get application object from any context (Context.getApplicationContext()) you easily can access this component.