# Inject activity using dagger

Tags: java, android, dagger-2

I try to create sample application with dagger 2 using mvp & RXAndroid, every thing work correctly but I cannot able to inject Activity the following is my AppComponent

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AppModule.class})
public interface AppComponent {
    void inject(App app);

    void inject(MainActivity activity);

    void inject(ResponseService service);

    void inject(MainPresenter presenter);
}
```

and the following is my Module

```
@Module
public class AppModule {

    private App app;
    public AppModule(App app) {
        this.app = app;
    }
    private static final String API_ENDPOINT = "url here";

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public ApiService apiService() {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();


        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapterFactory(new ClassTypeAdapterFactory())
                .registerTypeAdapter(Class.class, new ClassTypeAdapter()).create();


        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(API_ENDPOINT)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .client(client)
                .build();

        return retrofit.create(ApiService.class);
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    ResponseService responseService() {
        return new ResponseService(app.getComponent());
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    MainPresenter mainPresenter() {
        return new MainPresenter(app.getComponent());
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    EventBus eventBus() {
        return EventBus.getDefault();
    }
}
```

I inject all things correctly and can work with them  except `ManiActivity`  when try to use it give me null pointer the following how i inject it

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ((App) getApplicationContext())
            .getComponent()
            .inject(this);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    initRecyclerView();
    presenter.setView(this);
}
```

but when try to use it as Context in My adapter and pass it to Picasso library give me the following exception `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Context must not be null.`
 the following is how i use it

```
@Inject
MainActivity activity;
```

and use it in onBindViewHolder as following

```
Picasso.with(activity).load(response).fit().into(holder.ivCover);
```

My adapter code

```
public class ReAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ReAdapter.RViewHolder> {
    private List<Response> responseList;

    @Inject
    MainActivity appContext;


    public ReAdapter() {
    }

    public void setResponseList(List<Response> responseList) {
        this.responseList = responseList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public RViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, final int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.response_item, parent, false);
        return new RViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Response response = responseList.get(position);
            Picasso.with(appContext).load(response.getValue().toLowerCase()).fit().into(holder.ivd);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return responseList != null ? responseList.size() : 0;
    }


    public class RViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        @BindView(R.id.ivd)
        ImageView ivd;

        public RViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me to solve this issue ?

Comment: are you calling AppComponent.inject in your adapter?

Comment: Please include the code in question, describe where and how you're injecting/creating your objects, and don't just show one line of code. I'm guessing you just added some `@Inject` to your code and wonder why nothing happens? e.g. see [here for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47675483/1837367)

Comment: @RafalMalek In my activity only

Comment: Even if you can, you would NEVER want to inject an Activity.  At most you'd want to inject a Context.  And you'd prefer to do so with the application context, not the activity one.

Comment: @DavidMedenjak check updated question

Comment: @GabeSechan do you mean inject Context only ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Your activity: `MainActivity` doesn't have an `@Inject` annotated constructor (and can't have, because it's created by the system).
- In your `AppModule` there is no `@Provides` annotated method that returns `MainActivity`.
- You are injecting the fields in your activity not in your adapter.

The result is `Dagger` has no idea how to create an object of type `MainActivity`.

The solution for this specific problem is to use the application context for `Picasso` or even better create a `Picasso` object with `Dagger`.

Update your `AppModule` with:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
Picasso providePicasso(App app) {
    return Picasso.with(app);
}
```

In `MainActivity` add a field:

```
@Inject
ReAdapter adapter;
```

In `ReAdapter` modify the constructor and add a field for picasso:

```
private final Picasso picasso;

@Inject
public ReAdapter(Picasso picasso) {
    this.picasso = picasso;
}
```

This way `Dagger` can create a singleton `Picasso` instance. The `ReAdapter` is annotated with @Inject (using constructor injection) so `Dagger` knows how to create it. By adding a `ReAdapter` field in `MainActivity` when you call `component.inject(this)` in `MainActivity` the adapter field will be initialized.

Comment: and get Picasso from my MainActivity by @Inject ?

Comment: @Ahmed updated my question with an explanation of what happens.